# Visual Studio Won't Update C++ Version

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to use the `<filesystem>` library, and for that I need C++17 or later. I went to the project properties, to General, then to "C++ language standard", and set the language to C++20. But when I compile, it says that the library is only available with C++17 or later, and doesn't let me use it.

I went to the `<filesystem>` header document and saw that the `_HAS_CXX17` macro was defined as false, which was causing the problems. I went to the location where the `_HAS_CXX17` macro was defined, `vcruntime.h`, and tried setting it to true, but Visual Studio doesn't allow users to edit that file.

This problem is puzzling to me, as I have used the `<filesystem>` library in other projects, and the C++ version updated without issues. I have not changed anything in my settings of the overall Visual Studio application, nor have I messed with any of its files before.

Comment: The typical mistake is to forget that the project properties have their own combo boxes for the configuration and platform. They are not synced with the currently active configuration/platform. Happens to me every now and then that I change something in the properties for a configuration/platform that is not the currently active one.

Comment: A common mishap is to change a setting for the wrong configuration or platform.  Project > Properties, pay attention to the two comboboxes at the top of the dialog.  Before you change this setting, you need to select "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".

Comment: I have used <filesystem> with C++20 on Visual Studio, so I suspect you have made one of the errors mentioned above. You certainly should not be trying to edit system header files to solve your problems. That is madness.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Yes, and thanks Hans Pasant and Sedenion for your answers

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Since I was the first one to point out the mistake in the comments, I took the liberty of posting an answer.

Comment: Try [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [git](https://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already suspected in the comments and as confirmed by the OP, the problem was that the OP changed the properties for a configuration and/or platform which was not the currently active one. It is quite easy to forget to select the desired one in the properties dialog since the combo boxes in the properties are not synced with the ones that determine the active configuration/platform.
See the following image:
[image]