# Visual Studio is using wrong C++ version

Tags: visual-studio, c++17, c++14, compiler-version

In Visual Studio I changed the compiler version from C++17 to C++14, but based on compiler errors it appeared to still be using C++17.  Sure enough, _MSVC_LANG says 201703 and _HAS_CXX17 is true.

This is despite the fact that Project Properties says "ISO C++14 Standard" under both
C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard and General > C++ Language Standard, for All Configurations and All Platforms.

Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

---

What I tried:

1. Searched StackOverflow for an answer; this one looked like it would do the trick: [Visual Studio Won't Update C++ Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705449/visual-studio-wont-update-c-version), but the solution didn't work as I'm already setting All Configurations and All Platforms.
2. Searched for additional settings in VS that might be superseding my C++14 setting
3. Searched the web

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!  The project settings were all fine, but the settings for the source file, specifically, were set to C++17 for Debug-x64, specifically.  I didn't even know that was possible; how advisable is it for different parts of the same project to use different C++ versions?

Anyway, noob mistake, thanks for the below response.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck Project Properties Thoroughly:

A- Carefully examine all configurations and platforms (Debug, Release, x86, x64, etc.) under both C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard and General > C++ Language Standard. Ensure they're set to ISO C++14 Standard.

B- Pay close attention to any conditional compilation flags that might be overriding the C++14 setting.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding (B), this problem only happens with Debug-x64 not Release-x64 or Win32; examining the compilation command line, the only differences are that Debug-x64 sets /JMC, /RTC1, /MDd, and doesn't set /GL, /Gy, /Oi, /MD.  These would not seem to explain the problem.  FWIW the flag /std:c++14 is set for both.

Comment: Still no luck.  Since the command-line arguments (in C/C++ > Command Line) don't look fishy, I'm wondering if it could be the compiler executable itself that's C++17 instead of C++14. (I assume there's a different executable for each C++ version).  Is there a way to verify this?  (Maybe it should go without saying but yes, I still have the version set to C++14 in both C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard and in General > C++ Language Standard)